# Every other boot up of the system crashes after a couple minutes even with no user activity

Tags: kernel, amdgpu

Recent install of Ubuntu 22.10 Kernel   5.19.0-26-generic
AMD RX 6700 XT PCIE graphics card
AMD Ryzen 5 2600 CPU

Every first boot of the day crashes after a minute or two no matter the activity.
GPU driver was installed using `amdgpu-install_5.4.50401-1_all.deb` from AMD.com with [these installation instructions](https://amdgpu-install.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install-script.html#invoking-the-amdgpu-install-script).

When comparing a boot up which is stable and lasts all day with a crash log of a crashed system, the following is different between the two:

```
--------------------
Jan 08 12:23:01 pvarn-System-Product-Name appimagelauncherd[1813]: Directories to watch disappeared, unintegrating AppImages formerly found in there
Jan 08 12:23:03 pvarn-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: systemd-localed.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan 08 12:23:04 pvarn-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan 08 12:23:10 pvarn-System-Product-Name geoclue[1521]: Service not used for 60 seconds. Shutting down..
Jan 08 12:23:10 pvarn-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: geoclue.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan 08 12:23:33 pvarn-System-Product-Name systemd[1805]: Started Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
Jan 08 12:23:33 pvarn-System-Product-Name systemd[1805]: Started Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
Jan 08 12:23:34 pvarn-System-Product-Name gnome-shell[2025]: JS WARNING: [resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/overrides/Gio.js 287]: Too many arguments to method Gio.AsyncInitable.init_async: expected>
Jan 08 12:23:34 pvarn-System-Product-Name ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com[2025]: unable to update icon for software-update-available
Jan 08 12:23:38 pvarn-System-Product-Name PackageKit[1522]: uid 1000 is trying to obtain org.freedesktop.packagekit.system-sources-refresh auth (only_trusted:0)
Jan 08 12:23:38 pvarn-System-Product-Name PackageKit[1522]: uid 1000 obtained auth for org.freedesktop.packagekit.system-sources-refresh
Jan 08 12:23:38 pvarn-System-Product-Name PackageKit[1522]: refresh-cache transaction /332_ebdcacbb from uid 1000 finished with success after 822ms
Jan 08 12:23:39 pvarn-System-Product-Name dbus-daemon[1826]: apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="session" path="/ca/desrt/dconf/Writer/user" interface="ca.desrt.dconf.Writer" member="Cha>
Jan 08 12:23:39 pvarn-System-Product-Name snap-store[2324]: failed to commit changes to dconf: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending th>
Jan 08 12:23:39 pvarn-System-Product-Name snapd[837]: storehelpers.go:748: cannot refresh: snap has no updates available: "bare", "core", "core18", "core20", "core22", "ffmpeg", "firefox", "gnome-3-38-20>
Jan 08 12:26:30 pvarn-System-Product-Name kernel: pcieport 0000:00:03.1: AER: Multiple Corrected error received: 0000:07:00.0
Jan 08 12:26:30 pvarn-System-Product-Name kernel: pcieport 0000:00:03.1: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
Jan 08 12:26:30 pvarn-System-Product-Name kernel: pcieport 0000:00:03.1:   device [1022:1453] error status/mask=00001100/00006000
Jan 08 12:26:30 pvarn-System-Product-Name kernel: pcieport 0000:00:03.1:    [ 8] Rollover              
Jan 08 12:26:30 pvarn-System-Product-Name kernel: pcieport 0000:00:03.1:    [12] Timeout               
Jan 08 12:26:30 pvarn-System-Product-Name kernel: amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
Jan 08 12:26:30 pvarn-System-Product-Name kernel: amdgpu 0000:07:00.0:   device [1002:67df] error status/mask=00001100/00002000
Jan 08 12:26:30 pvarn-System-Product-Name kernel: amdgpu 0000:07:00.0:    [ 8] Rollover              
Jan 08 12:26:30 pvarn-System-Product-Name kernel: amdgpu 0000:07:00.0:    [12] Timeout               
Jan 08 12:26:30 pvarn-System-Product-Name kernel: amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: AER:   Error of this Agent is reported first
Jan 08 12:26:30 pvarn-System-Product-Name kernel: pcieport 0000:00:03.1: AER: Multiple Corrected error received: 0000:00:00.0
Jan 08 12:26:30 pvarn-System-Product-Name kernel: pcieport 0000:00:03.1: AER: can't find device of ID0000
--------------------
```

GPU device information:

```
ID  PCI 1002:67df:1462:3417
Class   03-00 »
Type    graphics card »
Vendor  AMD »
Name    Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590]
Subsystem   Micro-Star International [MSI]
```

If there is a chipset installation for Ubuntu and this ASUS MB I've not been able to find it.

Installed:

```
PCI     1022:43eb:1b21:1062 »
/ 01-06-01  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]  500 Series Chipset SATA Controller  storage     ahci
```

Sources indicate support for the chipset is built into the Kernal and does not need a driver.

Comment: Since AMD does a much better job supporting their hardware under Linux than NVIDIA, I wonder why you installed an arbitrary deb file instead of using the hardware install from Ubuntu. Mind to explain? This looks like the answer: `Sources indicate support for the chipset is built into the Kernal and does not need a driver.`

Comment: This is all I knew to do at the time.  When the system doesn't crash, it's dong everything I want with professional audio.  Will this "hardware install" (never heard of it) install over what I have or do I have to throw away a couple weeks worth of work to get everything set up and working?

Comment: I've not been able to find any firm information on this "hardware install:  In the initial install I enabled the automatic download of all necessary drivers and options.
The events just before the crash stand out to me:
"Timeout Jan 08 12:26:30 pvarn-System-Product-Name kernel: amdgpu"
"AER: can't find device of ID0000"

Comment: Then I'd recommend using the 22.04 Version. Everything after is "testing" and might not work.